# Run code before IIS reset/shutdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I have a MVC application that stores some information in memory and writes that data asynchronously to a database.

This mechanism works fine. However, I want to prevent an IISreset or a reboot to flush the data before it is written.

Is there a way to receive an event to tell IIS and/or the OS to run some handling code prior to shutting down?

(Update): **I am fully aware that I will never be able to detect a crash, hard reset etc**. Losing some data on a hard reset is not nice but I will deal with it (and make sure the application is usable after the server comes back).

Use the *"office metaphor"* to describe my approach: If you receive a BSOD, your work is lost if you haven't saved. But if you shutdown the way you should, you will be asked to save before.

Comment: Even if you can get this working, there's nothing you can do if the IIS process crashes, or even the OS. Better to not rely on such a mechanism.

Comment: I updated the question to clearify my approach

Comment: Can you outline why your application might need this? Is your IIS particularly at risk of crashing? I would guess that most web apps would be thought of as risking data corruption during a web server crash. The solution is to make the web server as stable as possible.

Comment: It is a server where continiously new applications (and updates for them) are being deployed. The admins usually do an iisreset "just in case". You can(and should) argue if this is necessary, but this is the normal approach on that machine